# Shutting down a Windows 7 machine sometimes restarts it instead

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown, reboot

The machine in question is running Windows 7 (64 Bit) on a Core i5 with 8 GB of RAM with all Windows Updates applied. Not that the specs should make a difference.

Shutting down this machine from the start menu or through `shutdown.exe - s` sometimes restarts it instead. Any clues as to what might be going on?

Comment: This can simply be a hardware issue with your BIOS, care to check if there is an upgrade for your hardware and see if that works?

Comment: It is possible for third-party software to do this.  I suggest you start by finding out whether it still happens if you explicitly log out and then shut down from the logon screen.

Comment: I realize you've mentioned that all updates are current, but I would still advise you double-check to ensure there are no updates pending installtion from Windows Update. Windows Update can seriously screw around with the system startup/shutdown sequence in that circumstance.

Comment: @DavidW: Thanks. I do keep windows up to date religiously. Since this issue is apparent on only one of my desktops, BIOS updates may very well be the reason like Bruno suggested.

Comment: @Harry: I have the same issue, even when I explicitly log out and then shut down from the logon screen.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: this applies to Win 7 installs 2 separate partitions (as described here), with all cables bar power & monitor unplugged. I'm wary of updating my BIOS as I want to reinstall OS X and am not sure this'll support a new BIOS version.

Comment: @tog22: provided you're not talking about a third-party firmware upgrade, but one provided by Apple, it shouldn't cause any problems reinstalling OS X.  (Perhaps check with a Macintosh expert first if you're concerned!  I believe StackExchange has a Mac forum.)  If you're using BootCamp, that might be related to this problem, I'm not sure how reliable BootCamp is these days.

Comment: Ah, I'm not actually using a Mac but a custom build (though I'm not sure how much SuperUser like people discussing this)