# Enabling AHCI fixed 0x0000007B BSOD on old Windows 7 partition - but now it restarts whenever I select shutdown

Tags: bsod, reboot

I built a PC that's been working for a while (aside: mainly using a non-Windows OS, which *seemed* to start kernel panicing more frequently). It stopped booting in any OS from the partitions on the SSD (giving BSOD 'STOP: 0x0000007B (0x80786A58, 0xC0000034, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)').

I installed Windows 7 on a separate drive and magicandre1981 kindly explained how to make the old SSD partition work by switching to AHCI mode in BIOS (and make the [new HD partition work by enabling AHCI](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976)).

However since this whenever I select shutdown in either Win 7 partition, the machine restarts instead (it shuts down in 1 out of 10 attempts). This happens even when I explicitly log out and then shut down from the logon screen, and even with all cables bar power & monitor unplugged. [This SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/455718/shutting-down-a-windows-7-machine-sometimes-restarts-it-instead) suggests updating to BIOS, but I'm not sure other OSes I want to reinstall/reenable will work after this. I'm no BIOS expert, but have changed a few relevant-seeming settings, and mine look much like [the bottom half of these ones](http://lnx2mac.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/optimal-bios-configuration.html).

Comment: have you changed the SATA mode in the BIOS from AHCI to IDE or IDE to AHCI?

Comment: I just did. In IDE mode the old Win 7 SSD partition gives the 0x7b error, while the new Win 7 HD partition works; in AHCI mode it's vice versa. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, change the SATA mode back to the IDE so that you can boot into Windows with your HDD, and read the KB article to enable AHCI:

**Error message occurs after you change the SATA mode of the boot drive**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976

Now you can change the mode to AHCI again and boot into the HDD and SSD.

Comment: Thanks! I can now boot into both Win 7 partitions (HD and SSD). However shutting down either partition almost always restarts instead, as in [this unresolved SU question](http://superuser.com/questions/455718/shutting-down-a-windows-7-machine-sometimes-restarts-it-instead) - don't know if you can help with that?

Comment: Sorry is this is bad form, but I'm editing my question to explain this, and that it happens with the switch to AHCI, and so unaccepting your answer.

Comment: sorry, I have no idea why you have the other issue. I've never seen this.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to update your BIOS, following the manual for your specific motherboard.  I had a similar issue with booting my new build that was due to a BIOS issue with my particular SATA drive.  I would also update the drivers for all of your devices.

I have several other suggestions for you, but this site has just about all of the ones I could think of and provides guides to help you through many of them as well (including updating drivers), so I would suggest going through these and seeing what you can come up with.

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/stop0x0000007b.htm

Comment: Answer appreciated,though the other one worked!  I'm wary of updating my BIOS as I want to reinstall OS X and am not sure this'll support a new BIOS version.